# How do I know a Grails application is fully loaded?

Tags: grails

I'd like to set up such a listener in my Grails 2.2 application code...

Comment: what do you mean with 'fully loaded'?

Comment: Something like "ready to serve users".

Comment: That would be something specific about your server (Tomcat, JBoss, etc), not Grails.  Once you deploy grails it isn't really a grails app.  It's a JEE compliant web application.

Comment: Why server-specific? There is BootStrap.groovy at least (called too early although). There are Spring events also. I still believe it is possible to do without knowing your server...

Answer (score 0):

I tried the `init()` method of the `BootStrap` in both dev and prod. Looks like it's being called exactly before the server becomes ready to serve requests.